# Python not printing newline

Tags: python

I have script that seems to have stopped working after my latest upgrade. To find the problem, I wrote a little script:

```
import subprocess

hdparm = subprocess.Popen(["xargs","echo"],
                stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

hdparm.stdin.write("Hello\n")
hdparm.stdin.write("\n")
hdparm.stdin.close()
hdparm.wait()
quit()
```

This just prints "Hello" and a new line, but I expect two newlines. What's causing this? (I am using 2.7.3 at the moment)

EDIT: Here is the problematic script (edited for clarity):

```
hdparm = subprocess.Popen(["hdparm", "--please-destroy-my-drive", "--trim-sector-ranges-stdin", "/dev/sda"],
               stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
hdparm_counter = 0
for rng in ranges_to_trim:
    hdparm.stdin.write("%d:%d\n" % (rng["begin"],rng["length"]))
    hdparm_counter += 1
    if hdparm_counter > 63:
         hdparm.stdin.write("\n")
         hdparm_counter = 0
if hdparm_counter != 0:
    hdparm.stdin.write("\n")
hdparm.stdin.close()
hdparm.wait()
```

EDIT: I believe the problem is with my script itself. I need to send EOF to hdparm to make it do whatever it is supposed to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the `xargs` man page:

> This manual page documents the GNU version of xargs.  xargs reads items from the standard input, delimited by
>   blanks (which can be protected with double or single quotes or a backslash) or  newlines,  and  executes  the
>   command (default is /bin/echo) one or more times with any initial-arguments followed by items read from stan‐
>   dard input.  **Blank lines on the standard input are ignored.**

(emphasis added).

Also, to add -- the newline you see is from `echo` itself.  `xargs` doesn't pass it along anyway.

Comment: The problem is that I actually pipe this to `hdparm --trim-sector-ranges-stdin` which has the same effect. Until recently, the newline character was piped correctly and everything worked. I did a system update, and now hdparm receives a huge line of ranges to trim that it cannot process.

Comment: It might be useful if you update the question with this information then so we can see what exactly you're doing for that case.

Comment: I added the script that is giving me trouble